# Optimizing and compressing mysql db with drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, optimization, innodb

I have developed a news website in a local language(utf-8) which server average 28k users a day. The site has recently started to show much errors and slow down. I got a call from the host saying that the db is using almost 150GB of space. I believe its way too much for the db and think there something critically wrong however i cannot understand what it could be. The site is in Drupal and the db is Mysql(innoDb). Can any one give directions as to what i should do.

UPDATE: Seems like innoDb dump is using the space. What can be done about it? Whats the standard procedure to deal with this issue.

Comment: 150G is certainly huge, but you really need to check which tables are that big. One canditate if you have a a lot of content is the search index, or maybe session/cache/access logs aren't cleaned up.

Comment: I assume you run cron on a timed basis and that cron actually finished (ie not dies on a fatal error)? Drupal does a lot of cleaning in cron; if your cron fails, tables such as watchdog, accesslog or sesssions can rapidly grow out of hand.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'InnoDB dump'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question does not have enough info for a specific answer, maybe your code is writing the same data to the DB multiple times, maybe you are logging to the table and the logs have become very big, maybe somebody managed to get access to your site/DB and is misusing it.

You need to login to your database and check which table is taking the most space. Use `SHOW TABLE STATUS` ([link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html)) which will tell you the size of each table. Then manually check the data in the table to figure out what is wrong.